# Installing Ubuntu on MacBook Pro 11.2/11.3

Tags: macbook-pro

Has anyone successfully installed Ubuntu on the new MacBook Pro (late-2013)?

If not, what issues have you had?

If so, did you use a tutorial, which one?

Comment: Have you tried to install it? Ubuntu should be smart enough to no to give problems.

Comment: Your question is worded in such a way that people will turn away from it. It assumes 1. someone has a new MacBook. 2. someone wants Ubuntu on it 3. someone is registered here and 4. is willing to post all that went wrong with their installation. Question have a lot more traction when you run into problems trying to install Ubuntu and ask about those problems. The problems you run into do not need to be because of using a Mac so might have a wider audience ;)

Comment: Besides all that: I went on a searching spree and below is the best I could find :) (even though I do not own a Mac (and never will :D ))

Comment: Oh come on @Rinzwind, MacBooks are *só* great ... for installing Ubuntu on :-).  I got my MBP in 2011, after 15+ years on Linux. The single thing I'm sorry about is that I didn't put Ubuntu on it earlier :D.

Comment: Oh the hardware is astonishing. It's the companies morals I detest ;) @zwets

Answer (score 4):

I have not found anything on the web related to 11.2 or 11.3. 11.1 is the closest I got and is also late 2013. Assuming no regressions this is the best you get:

> ### Has anyone successfully installed Ubuntu on the new MacBook Pro (late-2013)?

See below; last blockquote.

> ### If not, what issues have you had?

Doesn't work:

- Speakers
- iSight
- Suspend / Resume (resumes to black screen)

[Source: conan.jen@ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184760&p=12833429#post12833429).

- [This fixes sound for some](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1247475).

> ### If so, did you use a tutorial, which one?
>
> 1. Downloaded 13.10 NON-MAC iso.
> 2. Put it onto flash drive via unetbootin.
> 3. Boot up with option held at startup, and select the usb drive.
> 4. Upon installer bootup, went into advanced section and deleted all partitions.
> 5. Created an efi boot partition at 200mb. Installer should auto set the mount point 
>      on that partition to /boot/efi, but make sure.
> 6. Created a normal ext4 partition mounted to /, for the system installation point.
> 7. Continued on setup.

[Source: conan.jen@ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184760&p=12835803#post12835803).

> Thank you Conan for your lead! I have successfully installed Ubuntu
>   13.10 on a MacBookPro11,1 (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013). The installation went smoothly but I could not boot into Ubuntu. After
>   hours of trying, I finally figured it out. The following are what I
>   did (same steps as Conan's except Step 5):
>
> 1. Download 13.10 NON-MAC iso and put it onto flash drive via Startup Disk Creator (or unetbootin).
> 2. Boot up with OPTION key held, and select the EFI icon to boot the flash drive.
> 3. Enter live mode (i.e. "Try Ubuntu").
> 4. Install. Wipe out existing partitions and create new ones: i) 200MiB efi, bootable, mounted to /boot/efi; ii) 20GiB ext4, mounted to
>      /; iii) 8GiB swap; iv) rest ext4, mounted to /home.
> 5. After installation, fix the EFI boot order (The EFI BootOrder was 0080 but ubuntu was listed as Boot0000*).
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install efibootmgr sudo efibootmgr ## display boot order information
>    sudo efibootmgr -o 0 ## set boot order to 0000 first
>    sudo restart -r now
>    ```
> 6. Edit grub configuration file `/etc/default/grub` (one line):
>
>    ```
>    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="libata.force=noncq" and then 'sudo update-grub'
>    ```
> 7. Install kernel 3.12. Thanks, kjano!
> 8. Fix speakers (following https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1247475). Thanks, kjano!
>
> (There is no need of rEFIt or rEFInd or boot-repair. I wasted hours
>   trying various options of boot-repair to no avail.)

[Source: lichun1668@ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184760&page=4&p=12840087#post12840087)

Comment: I just hope those aren't real mails :S

Answer (score 0):

**Speakers** also fixed for 11.3 using mba6 model setting.

for **11.1**:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools
sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x1 set_gpio_data 1
```

for **11.3** also set mba6 not mbp101: 
Refer [this bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=64401).

**HDMI to VGA** (e.g., for projector) requires and *active* adapter (that uses USB as power supply) but works fine. HDMI to HDMI works out of the box.

See [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184760) for updates.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed ubuntu budgie on my 2010 macbook pro and I have not faced any issues. I did face issues when trying to load ubuntu 19.04. Ubuntu budgie 19.04 was working ok but was slow. 
But ubuntu budgie 19.10 works seamlessly and I have not faced any issues so far. I used rufus to create the boot drive.

Answer (score -1):

Install iubuntu for macs, http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso ,  on a USB, and then use boot camp (preinstalled) to walk you through the steps.